# Sign in button not working with firebase authentication

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hi there people i cannot run the code on this and the sign in button doesnt respond to the firebase i have tried all the things but couldnt figure out the problem can you please help me on this one

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_project/hello/Courses.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class MyLogin extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyLogin({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyLogin> createState() => _MyLoginState();
}

class _MyLoginState extends State<MyLogin> {

final emailcontroller = TextEditingController();
  final passwordcontroller = TextEditingController();
   
   Future SignIn() async{
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: emailcontroller.text.trim(), password: 
    passwordcontroller.text.trim());
   }
   @override
  void dispose() {
    emailcontroller.dispose();
    passwordcontroller.dispose();
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
  }
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('assets/hello.jpg'),fit: BoxFit.cover)
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:35,top: 45),
              child: Text('Welcome Back,\nStudent',
               style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),fontSize: 20),),
               
            ),
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
                right: 35,
                left: 35),
                child: Column(children: [
                  TextField(
                    controller: emailcontroller,
                    
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      fillColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
                      filled: true,
                      hintText: 'Email',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10))
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    controller: passwordcontroller,
                    
                    obscureText: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      fillColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
                      filled: true,
                      hintText: 'Password',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10))
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 40,),
                 ElevatedButton.icon(style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  minimumSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
                 ), icon: Icon(Icons.lock_open,size: 32,), label: Text(
                  'Sign In', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                 ), onPressed: SignIn,),

            

                
           RichText(
            text: new TextSpan(
              children: [
                new TextSpan(
                  text: 'Forgot Your Password?, ',
                  style: new TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 226, 218, 218)),
                ),
                new TextSpan(
                  text: 'Click Here',
                  style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                  recognizer: new TapGestureRecognizer()
                    ..onTap = () { launch('https://www.dandenongclc.org.au/about-us');
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
                ]),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_project/hello/Courses.dart';

import 'package:my_project/hello/timetable.dart';
import 'login.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

Future main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, 
    initialRoute: 'login',
    routes: {
      'login':(context) => const MyLogin()
    },
    home: const Mainpage(),
  ));
}
 
class Mainpage extends StatelessWidget {
  const Mainpage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) 
        {
          if (snapshot.hasData){
            return Courses();
          }
          
          
          return MyLogin();
        }
      ),);
  }
}
```

I was expecting the sign in button to configure with firebase as i have added the user authentication with email and password on firebase but whenever i click the sign i cannot go through to the page i linked to here are my main.dart and my login.dart file can you help guys

Comment: I can run the code and the app but still whenever i put the username and the password that i had in the firebase authentication the sign in button doesnt go through to the next page i have desired in the main.dart file as you can see

Answer (score 0):

In Your Mylogin file use like this

```
 ElevatedButton.icon(style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  minimumSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
                 ), icon: Icon(Icons.lock_open,size: 32,), label: Text(
                  'Sign In', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                 ),onPressed: ()async {
                   await SignIn();
                  },),
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but still not working :(

Comment: please add your error to the question

Comment: 2
W/System  ( 9793): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/EGL_emulation( 9793): app_time_stats: avg=8.05ms min=3.35ms max=42.54ms count=36
W/System  ( 9793): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/TrafficStats( 9793): tagSocket(136) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
3
W/System  ( 9793): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/FirebaseAuth( 9793): Notifying id token listeners about user ( pLOG6TGruyR6pFg0aaQsZFXeisv1 ).
3
W/System  ( 9793): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.

Comment: the app runs fine but i get this in my debug console

Comment: just the button doesnt redirect to the desired page

Comment: what is that meaning ? in your firebase console did you have the logged account details under Authentication tab

Comment: yes i have the logged account details and whenever i enter the wrong account details the vs code says no email or password found in the firebase authentication but that must be normal just the sign in cannot go through other page with this code